# Android device for birds

Tags: applications, touchscreen, accessibility, user-interface

I would like to know if there exist any Android devices for birds. I've seen my little bird born from his or her egg in an incubator approach my companion's touch screen to peck on it after she showed him or her how to eat food by pointing in a pecking motion with the finger on the food, after which the bird ate.

Alas, my Android device did not respond to the bird's beak, pecking on the touch phone's screen.

I wonder whether there are any screens designed for beaks.

And, what would be possible, for a bird's interacting system, on an Android device?

Anyone know?

Thanks.

Note: This post asks about the possibility of bird to smartphone interfaces, as I know of none, and I'm not sure of Who would know. I was not sure if this was more appropriate on Android stack exchange or in biology stack exchange or in hardware recommendations stack exchange, or even on software engineering stack exchange. Or even obmn user experience (UX) stack exchange.

Please, if not appropriate here, migrate my post as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Mobile device touch screens have been made with resistive or capacitive technology.

Resistive required pressure to indicate location so normally used a pen/stylus. Capacitive uses the fact that the skin conducts and by interacting alters the screen's electric field marking position.

Birds tapping on a screen with a beak made of keratin isn't what the device was tuned for. The interaction by the bird is similar to a person with long fingernails using the tip on the screen. Personally I'm not even sure if pecking can activate a resistive screen as the pressure isn't similar to handwriting/human interaction and a certain amount of threshold is required to avoid false positive. However you can still get resistive screen Android devices which are targeted for industrial/construction environments.

Other than a resistive screen, my guess is that any interaction with birds and a screen would required a speciality device like a infrared grid or other similar setup which could detect the intrusion but to my knowledge is usually for large TV-ish screen sizes, i.e. digital chalkboards and kiosk signage.